# Xcode 6.1 - adding external source folder reference and compiling it's contents automatically

Tags: xcode, xcode6

Is there a way to add an external folder with C++ code to my project and be able to compile it's contents without having to add everything under "Compile Sources"? This is so if new source is added, it will get compiled automatically.

I've tried adding the external folder in "Compile Sources" itself and it appears, but nothing inside of it gets compiled.

[image: Link to "Compile Sources"]